# Wordpress + postfix + unsolicited emails being sent even if the email account wasn't created

Tags: php, wordpress, email, postfix-mta

I run a blog on wordpress. Recently I received a abuse complaints from the server which when verified returned this:

```
============================================================ 
Received: from [192.241.188.154] by usfamily.net 
(USFamily MTA v5/:PG5vcm1hX2NoYW1iZXJzQG1yaW5hbHB1cm9oaXQuY29tPjxkamtpbm5leUB1c2ZhbWlseS5uZXQ_)
with SMTP id <20140301115044001084500013> for <djkinney@usfamily.net>; 
Sat, 01 Mar 2014 11:50:44 -0600 (CST) 
(envelope-from norma_chambers@myblog.com, notifiable emailnetwork 192.241.188.) 
Received: by myprimarydomain.com (Postfix, from userid 498) 
id 1C5EE1305AE; Sat, 1 Mar 2014 17:12:39 +0000 (UTC) 
To: djkinney@usfamily.net 
Subject: FW: Good day 
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 498:sslnEn.php 
From: "Norma Chambers" <norma_chambers@myblog.com> 
Reply-To: "Norma Chambers" <norma_chambers@myblog.com> 
X-Priority: 3 (Normal) 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Message-Id: <20140301171239.1C5EE1305AE@myblog.com> 
Date: Sat, 1 Mar 2014 17:12:39 +0000 (UTC) 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div> 
<p> 
Top Meds Website good deal <a href=3D"http://dumantarim.com/modules/mod_= 
araticlhess/rlf.html">http://dumantarim.com/modules/mod_araticlhess/rlf.h= 
tml</a> 
</p> 
</div>

============================================================
```

Now I assumed that it meant this:
Several unsolicited emails were sent from the id norma_chambers@myblog.com. If my assumption is correct, this email id should have existed on the VPS AND user had access to the email account to send mails. Does it really means that my server (VPS) was hacked?

Am I on the correct path to trace this problem? Please shed some light.

Comment: Is there a contact form or a 'send this page to someone' function on your blog?

Comment: Yes I have a comment box below every blog post

Comment: But that cannot send an email. I was talking about contact, not comment. It looks like someone is abusing that kind of `send an email to someone` function. Could also be the Wordpress is not the most current version and thers is a security issue.

Comment: No I don't have any such functionality. No contact form as well!

Comment: I think you might better ask this on http://serverfault.com/ or http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Maybe you are not actively _displaying_ an email form on your site, but the necessary (default) routes to it are set up by WP anyway, and some spammer is just sending the right parameters to it …? Update your WP and all plugins to the latest version, and check your configuration thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as a workaround that helped me. By simply changing the directory path for wordpress from \wordpress\ to \dennis\ fixed 99% of these problems. It would appear that most of these attacks are based on default names and paths.